# Is it ok to re-assign the rootviewcontroller of the window again and again in this case...?

Tags: iphone, objective-c, ios, uisplitviewcontroller

I have a splitviewcontroller based application, but the problem is the split view comes into picture after two modal views.

1. for login
2. some other useful info for the user.

Now I know that splitview controller should always be the root view controller. So what i do is create three objects in my appDelegate class. 
A , B, and split view controller C.

the order of navigation is A-->B-->C;

so in the app delegate this is what i do..

```
self.loginViewController=[[LoginViewController alloc] init];
self.window.rootViewController = self.loginViewController;
```

and then once the login button is pressed this is what I do from the loginView controller..

```
TSAppDelegate *appDelegate=(TSAppDelegate *)[[UIApplication sharedApplication] delegate];
                appDelegate.meetingsViewController=[[MeetingsViewController alloc] init];
                [UIView
                 transitionWithView:appDelegate.window 
                 duration:0.8
                 options:UIViewAnimationOptionTransitionCrossDissolve
                 animations:^(void) {
                     BOOL oldState = [UIView areAnimationsEnabled];
                     [UIView setAnimationsEnabled:NO];
                     appDelegate.window.rootViewController=appDelegate.meetingsViewController;    
                     [UIView setAnimationsEnabled:oldState];
                 } 
                 completion:nil];
```

this here presents the second view...
and similarly I show the split view controller if some action is performed on the second view controller...

So my question is if it is the correct way to do it... ? (This works fine by the way and also its an enterprise application)

P.S. I also tried making the split view controller as the rootviewcontroller and adding the other view controllers views as its subview but that doesn't work properly.

Comment: > *and also its an enterprise application*  Hahahaha. What does that even mean?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Sure, it's perfectly fine to reassign the window's `rootViewController`.

Comment: Thanks..  just needed that confirmation for someone as experienced as you.